# Jquery Masonry height issue

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I have a simple masonry grid. When it loads the `.content` class is visible. When you *reload* the items flow in to each other.

This only happen in Chrome and Safari, in Firefox it looks good.

Here is the css from the grid:

```
#media_list {} 
#media_list .media_item  {  height: auto; width: 270px; display: inline-block; background: #f4f4f4; border: 1px solid #d9d7d5; float: left; padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px; font: 11px Helvetica Neue; }
#media_list .media_item .date { color: white;  background: #2f343a; padding: 10px 5px; width: 260px; float: left; margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;}
#media_list .media_item .content { padding: 15px; float: left; display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 20px; }
#media_list .media_item img { border: 1px solid #dedddd;  margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px; width: 248px;}
```

This is how masonry is called:

```
$('#media_list').masonry({  // options
                            itemSelector : '.media_item',
                            columnWidth : 300
                         });
```

I can work around it with `min-height`s and `margin`s but that's not dynamic and doesn't look very clean.

Here is [a JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jojoroxursox/kV5tu/) but it doesnt really replicate the issue.

Comment: if i run $('#media_list').masonry('reload'); in the console it resolves the issue. not sure how to make this happen every time it loads though

Comment: I dont quite understand the problem :( What is it doing wrong? And you could always extend the masonry with reload like you said :p

Comment: well I two things. 1) why does it look different when you access it straight from the url vs when you press reload. 2) whats a good jquery event to use to execute the $('#media_list').masonry('reload');  command?

Comment: I did not know about $('#TheMasonryContainer').masonry('reload');
tks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Seems you already use the reload.
Maybe its because the images reload on URL refresh and not on reload.

Try:

```
var $container = $('#media_list');
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.media_item',
        columnWidth : 300,
        gutterWidth: 20
  });
});
```

otherwise

```
$('#media_list').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector : '.media_item',
    columnWidth : 300,
    gutterWidth: 20
}).masonry('reload');
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the imagesLoaded plugin -- thanks for that! More info on the plugin here: http://metafizzy.co/blog/imagesloaded-plugin/

Comment: nice, but it's 'gutter', not 'gutterWidth'

Answer (score 10):

For a better compatibility with Google Chrome for example, change

```
var $container = $('#media_list');
```

to

```
$(window).load(function(){ $('#media_list').masonry(); });
```

Comment: this seems to make better sense if you have a lot of JS loading too. My layout would get wonky with it on doc.ready ... so thanks for the solution

Comment: This worked for me. Needed this with the combination of imagesLoaded().