# Jquery Masonry - images do not render on browser refresh on chrome and safari

Tags: jquery-masonry

We have used jquery masonry for tiling on our site.We are using the imagesLoaded function to show the tiles only when all the images have been loaded. Everything is working fine on firefox but the issues are on safari and chrome. On Safari and Chrome the images are not rendered on browser refresh. We are not able to figure out where to check and what the issue could be. Any help would be great.

the following is a link to our test site where you can see this in action.

http://valuri.actful.com/?invite=yes#

Thanks
Asif

Comment: The image path(src) is incorrect i think so! Check if your path is correct.

Comment: Suraj, Thanks for your reply, but I checked and the image paths seems to be fine except for the second tile for which it is wrong and we are aware of that. but the src for other tiles are all good. As I said, this works on firefox and this issue only happens on chrome and safari and only on page refresh. so this is a little baffling.

Answer (score 0):

The solution on this question might help:

[Jquery Masonry height issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256695/jquery-masonry-height-issue)

You might also want to check this answer:

[jquery masonry breaks(stacks images) in chrome/safari but only on first load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476649/jquery-masonry-breaksstacks-images-in-chrome-safari-but-only-on-first-load)